# Custom post query in single post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created some custom post type like works, photos, tutorials. when i query in my home page and the template page it working properly but when i am query in single-works.php all post redirect to last added post. the permalink shows the correct url but when single-works page open, it opens with the last added post. that is the problem?? I can not find any problem

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="page-section">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/banner.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="page-section-text">
        <h2>Our Works</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="blog-area padding fix">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <?php $wor= new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => 'works',
                'posts_per_page' => 1
            ));?>
            <?php if($wor->have_posts()):?>
            <?php while($wor->have_posts()): $wor->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="blog">
                    <div class="blog-image">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="blog-text">
                        <h2 style="font-size:25px"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile;?>
            <?php else :?>
                <h3><?php _e('404 Error&#58; Not Found'); ?></h3>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

it always shows the last post that i'm added. When i'm clecking the permalink in template-works.php it shows the correct link whin hover but after clicking in whatever post it always goes to the lastly added post. please help me.....

Comment: what happens when you set posts_per_page to -1?

Comment: if the link is correct but your installation directs you to the wrong file then there is probably something wrong with your .htaccess/permalink setting. Could you share a link?

Comment: You want to show all your post under works in single-works.php?

Comment: I want to view this post
http://localhost/diups/work/demo-work-two/
but this is viewing
http://localhost/diups/work/nai-nai-anoa/
the link of address bar is correct but post is not........... @RST

Comment: no.... only the single post @NirojAdhikary

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to write any custom query in single-works.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area texture">
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title single-post-title">', '</h2>' ); ?>  
     <?php the_content(); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

You can also get ID of current post inside while loop by using

```
 global $post;
 $post->ID;
```

Or use
    get_the_ID();